# Where can I get information on network congestion?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I've had a mining reward sitting at 1/60 confirmations for 5 days. I have also been unable to complete transactions due to timing out.

Usually, a default, lower priority transaction will make it. The last couple days, not even a Fast priority transaction will get through on time.

I have been using the latest monero-wallet-gui on Linux, as well as the updated monerod.

Is this a network problem?

Answer (score 1):

There's been no noticeable congestion in the last few days. One way to see this is to use the `bc_dyn_stats` command, which takes the number of blocks to consider for the stats. Here, we see the stats over the last 5000 blocks (with 720 blocks a day target, this is about a week):

`bc_dyn_stats 5000
Height: 1407694, diff 30128085264, cum. diff 3696203931783216, target 120 sec, dyn fee 0.000252520000/kB
Last 5000: avg. diff 29701519077, 119 avg sec/block, avg num txes 5.3806, avg. reward 6.451334569868, median block size 54240
Block versions: 5000 v6
Voting for: 5000 v6`

We see the median block size is just 54240 bytes, and the minimum block size limit is 300000 bytes, so there is plenty of space to spare. Of course, this does not mean there can't have been a massive glut at some point, and little traffic for the rest of the week, but that seems unlikely.

About the "mining reward sitting at 1/60 confirmations for 5 days", two things are important to note: First, transaction traffic (ie, congestion) has no real influence on the speed at which blocks are mined. Whether or not there is heavy use or light use, block time will continue to target 120 second (you can see the actual average was 119 second per block over the last week's worth of blocks, pretty close to target). Second, if a block you mined 5 days ago is still not seeing any further block, then either you're most likely disconnected from the network. This could happen if you're not finding any peer, or because you and the peers you find don't agree on the consensus rules. Note a fork happened a few days ago, on the 16th. I think you might be running Monero 0.10.3.1 ? If this is the case, you're out of date, and you may be mining on your own lone fork, and you need to switch to 0.11.0.0 to be able to follow the network again.

About transaction priority, it's very unlikely that a higher than default priority (and thus fee) will not be mined quick. The vast majority of transactions use the default fee, even in a glut, so a higher fee will be mined pretty fast - again, assuming you're on the correct fork, where miners are working.

Comment: I've been running 0.11.0.0 since September 7th. I just exited and restarted monerod. It told me it was 7 days behind. I'm not sure what happened. I'm waiting for it to finish syncing.

Comment: If it's still not catching up, restart with --log-level 1, wait for some syncing to be attempted, and file a bug on github with that log, please.

Comment: It synced. My mining reward isn't there, which really annoys me, but another transaction I've been waiting days for is synced. xmr.to worked quickly as well. I was mining on 0.11.0.0. I don't know it didn't tell me there was a problem. That bothers me.

Comment: You probably ended up on a fork somehow, and mined there. This is odd if you were on 0.11.0.0 though. You probably had no peers left (status would show 0+0 connections). This might explain your wording aobut transactions being not in time: maybe some did manage to get through if you can connect to a node for long enough for a tx to get through, but then get dropped. Could you double check you were really running 0.11.0.0 and not the old version by mistake ? You should see the version logged in the log file along with the timestamp on startup (~/.bitmonero/bitmonerod.log)

Comment: I finally got around to checking the logs:
2017-08-29 10:58:34.593 - Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.3.1-release) - 2017-09-10 22:32:08.733 - Monero 'Helium Hydra' (v0.11.0.0-release)
No idea what happened. Logs claim the new release on the 10th. History of the unconfirmed transaction appears to be gone from monero-ui. I see no "FOUND" block in the logs.
Being poor and severely depressed, this reward meant a ton to me. I know how pathetic that sounds. I'm pissed. (side note: Fuck the lack of markdown in comments.)